# No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

I am very new to spring 4.0. I am getting error "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken" while login attempt

Here are the files

ApplicationConfig Class

```
package com.springmaven.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;



@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.springmaven.service","com.springmaven.config"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.springmaven.repository",entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManager")
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean(name="datasource")
      public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/tms");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("mindfire");
        return dataSource;
      }


    /**
     * @return bean of entity manager
     */
    @Bean (name="entityManager")
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          em.setDataSource(dataSource());
          em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.springmaven.models" });

          JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
          em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          em.setJpaProperties(getJpaProperties());

          return em;
       }


    /**
     * @return Properties used to initialize entityManager Bean
     */
    private Properties getJpaProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
            return properties;
        }

     @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }

    /**
     * @return a bean of transaction manager
     */




}
```

DispatherServlet Class

```
package com.springmaven.config;



import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.springmaven.controller","com.springmaven.service"})
public class DispatcherConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/JSP/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig class

```
package com.springmaven.config;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Qualifier("memberDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService memberDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider; 

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;



    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth
         .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
         .userDetailsService(memberDetailsService)
         .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assests/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/member").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('MEMBER')")
           .and()
           .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
                .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
                .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")     
                .and().csrf()
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage?logout"); 

    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }


    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

here isCutom Authentication Class

```
package com.springmaven.config;

import java.util.Collection;


import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import com.springmaven.account.MemberDetails;
import com.springmaven.models.Employee;

@Component("AuthenticationProvider")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


    private MemberDetails userService;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
              throws AuthenticationException {
                String username = authentication.getName();
                String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

                Employee member = (Employee) userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                if (member == null || !member.getEmployeeUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
                }

                if (!password.equals(member.getPassword())) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
                }

                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = member.getEmpRoles();

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(member, password, authorities);

            }

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }


}
```

UserDetailsService class

```
package com.springmaven.account;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.springmaven.models.Employee;
import com.springmaven.repo.AccountRepo;
import com.springmaven.models.EmployeeRole;;



@Service("memberDetailsService")
public class MemberDetails implements UserDetailsService {
    private final AccountRepo accountRepo;

    @Autowired
    public MemberDetails(AccountRepo accountRepo) {
        this.accountRepo = accountRepo;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employee member = accountRepo.findByEmployeeUserName(username);
        if(member == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find Employee " + username);
        }

        return new CustomEmployeeDetails(member);
    }

    private final static class CustomEmployeeDetails extends Employee implements UserDetails {


        private CustomEmployeeDetails(Employee employee) {
            super(employee);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return getEmployeeUserName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5639683223516504866L;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Employee employee){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(EmployeeRole empRole : employee.getEmpRoles()){
            System.out.println("UserProfile : "+empRole);
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+empRole.getRole()));
        }
        System.out.print("authorities :"+authorities);
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Custom Sucess handler class

```
package com.springmaven.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{


    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            System.out.println("Can't redirect");
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        String url="";

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =  authentication.getAuthorities();

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
            roles.add(a.getAuthority());
        }


            url = "/homePage";

        return url;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

    private boolean isUser(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_MEMBER")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Employee Class

```
package com.springmaven.models;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblemployee")
public class Employee   {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(name="ntEmpID")
    private Long accountId;

    @Column(name="vcEmployeeUserName")
    private String employeeUserName;

    @Column(name="vcEmailIdOff")
    private String officialEmailID;

    @Column(name="vcEmailIdPer")
    private String permanentEmailID;

    @Column(name="vcEmployeeFirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="vcEmployeeMiddleName")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="vcEmployeeLastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="vcPresentAdd")
    private String presentAdd;

    @Column(name="vcPermanentAdd")
    private String permanentAdd;

    @Column(name="vcHomePhoneNumber")
    private String homeNumber;

    @Column(name="vcOfficeNumber")
    private String officeNumber;

    @Column(name="vcSkills")
    private String skills;

    @Column(name="vcPassword")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="fsCV")
    private byte[] cvBlob;

    @Column(name="fsEmployeePic")
    private byte[] picBlob;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Emlpoyee_PROFILE", 
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "vcEmployeeUserName") }, 
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ntEmpRoleID") })
    private Set<EmployeeRole> empRoles = new HashSet<EmployeeRole>();

    public Long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public Set<EmployeeRole> getEmpRoles() {
        return empRoles;
    }

    public void setEmpRoles(Set<EmployeeRole> empRoles) {
        this.empRoles = empRoles;
    }

    public void setAccountId(Long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeUserName() {
        return employeeUserName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeUserName(String employeeUserName) {
        this.employeeUserName = employeeUserName;
    }

    public String getOfficialEmailID() {
        return officialEmailID;
    }

    public void setOfficialEmailID(String officialEmailID) {
        this.officialEmailID = officialEmailID;
    }

    public String getPermanentEmailID() {
        return permanentEmailID;
    }

    public void setPermanentEmailID(String permanentEmailID) {
        this.permanentEmailID = permanentEmailID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPresentAdd() {
        return presentAdd;
    }

    public void setPresentAdd(String presentAdd) {
        this.presentAdd = presentAdd;
    }

    public String getPermanentAdd() {
        return permanentAdd;
    }

    public void setPermanentAdd(String permanentAdd) {
        this.permanentAdd = permanentAdd;
    }

    public String getHomeNumber() {
        return homeNumber;
    }

    public void setHomeNumber(String homeNumber) {
        this.homeNumber = homeNumber;
    }

    public String getOfficeNumber() {
        return officeNumber;
    }

    public void setOfficeNumber(String officeNumber) {
        this.officeNumber = officeNumber;
    }

    public String getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(String skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public byte[] getCvBlob() {
        return cvBlob;
    }

    public void setCvBlob(byte[] cvBlob) {
        this.cvBlob = cvBlob;
    }

    public byte[] getPicBlob() {
        return picBlob;
    }

    public void setPicBlob(byte[] picBlob) {
        this.picBlob = picBlob;
    }
    public Employee() {
    }
     public Employee(Employee employee) {
            this.accountId = employee.accountId;
            this.firstName = employee.firstName;
            this.lastName = employee.lastName;
            this.officialEmailID = employee.officialEmailID;
            this.password = employee.password;
        }



}
```

EmployeeRole class

```
package com.springmaven.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tblemproles")
public class EmployeeRole implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(name="ntEmpRoleID")
    private Long roleId;

    @Column(name="vcEmployeeUserName")
    private String employeeUserName;

    @Column(name="vcRole")
    private String role;

    public Long getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Long roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeUserName() {
        return employeeUserName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeUserName(String employeeUserName) {
        this.employeeUserName = employeeUserName;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.role;
    }

}
```

AccountRepo Interface extending JPA repositories

```
package com.springmaven.repo;



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.springmaven.models.Employee;

@Repository
    public interface AccountRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>
    {
        public Employee findByEmployeeUserName(String employeeUserName);
        public Employee findByOfficialEmailID(String offEmaiID);
        public Employee save(Employee account);

    }
```

Error trace

```
16:13:39.790 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /loginPage at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
16:13:39.790 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/loginpage'; against '/loginpage'
16:13:39.790 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
16:13:39.791 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
16:13:39.791 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
16:13:39.791 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@1a33ab3
16:13:39.791 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /loginPage?error
16:13:39.805 [qtp6152563-16] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/loginPage?error'
```

I am just started learning and implementing Spring Security in Spring 4.0

Please help me in this.

Comment: Is there any link to see implementation of DaoAuthenticationProvider

Answer (score 1):

I think your "supports" method is wrong. It should be

```
@Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
```

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on that. Can you please tell the lines in which, I am making mistake